# Combine property setter "init and private" (C#9)

Tags: c#, properties, repository, aggregateroot, c#-9.0

I ask about the new C#9-feature "init property setter". Below an example of it:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public int Name { get; init; }
    public int Position { get; init; }
}
```

My question is how I can update the value of 'Position' after initialize. I want something like this:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public int Name { get; init; }
    public int Position { get; init + private set; }

    public void MoveMyClass(int newPositionIndex)
    {
        // Some business code...
        Position = newPositionIndex;
    }
}
```

---

In my real world project an instance of *MyClass* is initialized by entity framework. Then I call some business methods on it. The rule is that only business methods are allowed to set values on properties, so I want at least private setters. But if I have private setters then entity framework cannot initialize the properties.

Comment: No can do. This was pointed out during the design of `init`, but the current design stuck. The `init` accessor is actually a `set` accessor under the hood, and you can't have two `set` accessors

Comment: Private, protected, internal setters are not a problem for EF since it is using reflection (or code generation) for setting the property values when loading from database. EF Core even directly works with backing fields.

Comment: You can have private init: `public int Prop { get; private init; }` compiles fine

Comment: @JL0PD Thanks, but it only would make the setter private, so my other layer (EF-Core) could no longer init them.

Comment: @IvanStoev I call Select in EFCore an map the property by hand, sometimes with automapper. This code would not compile.

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for the background infos. Maybee the feature would be available in C#10

Comment: I didn't say anything about the code. Just because you wrote: "But if I have private setters then entity framework cannot initialize the properties". And I'm replying: EF Core is just fine with properties with no setters (just they are not mapped by default) or with private/protected/internal setters.  In other words, the real scenario issue you are describing doesn't exist.  This is all I meant, nothing more.

Comment: @Alois It won't be. The design of `init` simple precludes its use alongside `set`, since `init` and `set` are implemented as the same underlying thing

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this feature is not available for auto-properties in C#9.

To solve this issue I combine init with the full property style (instead auto property). Maybee C#10 or later would support such an access modifier.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private int _position;

    public int Id { get; init; }
    public int Name { get; init; }
    public int Position { get => _position; init => _position = value; }

    public void MoveMyClass(int newPositionIndex)
    {
        // Some business code...
        _position = newPositionIndex;
    }
}
```